# how to Apply AND operation in SQL

Tags: sql-server

My Query is like

```
Select * From T Where ID=1 AND ID=2 AND ID=3 And So On
```

These ID From Another Result Set Like  `Select ID From T2`

If I Apply IN Operation `SELECT * From T Where ID IN(1,2,3)` It shows if there is any entry for 1 or 2 or 3 But in my requirement their should be ID 1 AND 2 AND 3 
means ID IS 1,2,3 if 2 is not there result should be empty 
how to apply this query.

1,2,3 is from another result set so I can't use directly and means I can't use `where ID=1 AND ID=2 AND So On`

Comment: Please include the table definitions for both tables, and add some sample data.

Comment: I *guarantee* that there is *no* row in T where ID is simultaneously equal to both 1 and 2, and I haven't even seen your data yet. I think you're trying to make some kind of assertion about *multiple* rows, but you've really not explained it well yet.

Comment: its amazing that i dont understand what you are talking about at all but there is 6 answer

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
SELECT * From T Where ID IN(Select ID From T2 where ID is not NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your condition  `Where ID=1 AND ID=2 AND ID=3` is never going to fetch you any record, as `ID` column of each row can hold only 1 value, which can be either `1` or `2` or `3` but not all.

Ideally your query should be like

```
Select * From T Where ID=1 OR ID=2 OR  ID=3
```

Above query is equivalent to

```
SELECT * From T Where ID IN(1,2,3)
```

If you want to fetch the records where id exists in another table, there are multiple ways like

1- `EXISTS`

```
Select * From T t1 
Where exists
(
 select 1 from t2 as t2 where t2.id=t1.id
)
```

2- Using `IN`

```
Select * From T t1
where id in
(
 select id from t2
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The condition is applied to each row.  Each row has only one ID.  And so that ID can't be equal to 1 and equal to 2 and equal to 3.  You need to use OR.

```
where ID=1 OR ID=2 OR ID=3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @c2 INT
SELECT DISTINCT @c2 = COUNT(id) FROM T2

DECLARE @c1 INT
SELECT DISTINCT @c1 = COUNT(T.id) FROM T JOIN T2 on T.id=T2.id

SELECT * FROM T WHERE @c1 = @c2
```